# What does lm(psp(x,df=0) do in R?

Tags: r, lm

I have data with incidence rates for each quarter between 2015 and 2022. I am supposed to model the association of the incidence rates with the general time trend(quarter 1-40 as numeric value) and seasonality (quarter 4 is the reference category and compared to q1-q3) using least square regression. However, for the general time trend, I am supposed to use penalized splines. I want R to choose the optimal degrees of freedom, so I put df = 0.

Following code results in R:

```
model1 <- lm(IR ~ pspline(trend, df=0) + quarter, data = data)
```

As a result, I get 17 degrees of freedom. Several questions now arise:

1. What does this function actually do when applied to a lm()? As I understand splines of linear functional form are fit at different knots.
2. How can I find out how many knots have been set? Do they correspond to the degrees of freedom in this case or df+1?
3. Although the AIC is supposed to minimize complexity, visualization shows that the data is highly overfit and a lot of random variation is captured, leading to implausible predictions. How can that be?

I looked for information online but am highly confused as to whether the method works as described here(https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pspline/pspline.pdf) or here (https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/survival/versions/2.22/topics/pspline) or completely differently.

Best and thank you very much for your time! I am very grateful for any suggestions.

Comment: The `pspline` package doesn't actually have a `pspline()` function in it (it has only `sm.spline` and `smooth.Pspline`, so I'm assuming that your function is coming from the `survival` package: the results of `find("pspline")` should confirm that.

Comment: I suspect that `pspline` doesn't actually work as advertised outside of the `survival` package.  I would strongly suggest that you try `library(mgcv); model1 <- gam(IR ~ s(trend, bs = "tp") + quarter, data = data, method = "REML")` which will indeed fit a penalized (thin plate) regression spline